# Why do Democrats and Republicans ignore public opinion polls on major issues?

Tags: united-states, democracy, public-opinion, republican-party, democratic-party

When polled, the majority of Americans consistently believe in (1) a [national health care plan](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/2020-polls-national-health-care-plan-favored-by-most-americans-cbs-news-poll-finds/); (2) increased taxes, not fewer taxes, [on the wealthy](https://thehill.com/hilltv/what-americas-thinking/428747-new-poll-americans-overwhelmingly-support-taxing-the-wealth-of); (3) and more, not less, [environmental regulation](https://news.gallup.com/poll/232007/americans-want-government-more-environment.aspx), particularly on climate change.

**How can these politicians get away with opposing the views of the majority on major issues?**  In other words, why is there not meaningful choice in the political arena in the US?

Comment: Those 3 views you mentioned are the core Democratic priorities. So it seems like you're really asking why _Republicans_ ignore public opinion.

Comment: Is that the question you want answered? I think there are clear and specific reasons why Republican politicians are relatively insulated from public opinion on these and other issues, but that's not quite the question you have here.

Comment: In my view although several examples are cited, this is one general question and does not lack focus. It should not be closed on such grounds.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: this q is bad because everyone is going to have an opinion on why politicians are doing this, but few will be supportable with evidence (in particular actually proving causation). The answers below already illustrate the problem.

Comment: @ Fizz  that **might** be a reason to close as onion-based, but not as lacking focus. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: actually both (opinion-based, too broad) are reasons to VTC. It's not clear if the OP is looking for an explanation on those 3 issues or a completely generic answer that applies to any situation (and which frankly would not even be particular to the US, although most research on the matter was conducted there anyway). Since the causes why politicians act this way are multi-pronged, the weights can differ between concrete issues. It's unclear if the OP expects answers to get into the [weight] details (or not) on each issue.

Comment: @Fizz: I didn't think I had to establish common sense.  Here are three polls I found in 2 minutes of searching:  https://www.cbsnews.com/news/2020-polls-national-health-care-plan-favored-by-most-americans-cbs-news-poll-finds/      https://thehill.com/hilltv/what-americas-thinking/428747-new-poll-americans-overwhelmingly-support-taxing-the-wealth-of       https://news.gallup.com/poll/232007/americans-want-government-more-environment.aspx

Comment: @Fizz: the 3 issues are only examples of major issues.  They are not the question.  The question is in the second paragraph.  It has a question mark after it.

Comment: It's actually a somewhat different q that your title question. "How can they get away with it" is different from "why are they underestimating the problem" (title q). You''ll note that  Ryan's answer is only addressing your title question and your middle-of-the-post question. I voted to reopen since I bothered to write a bit more in my answer now, but your question is still very chameleonic. (I also have the impression, given your other comments, that you may be hunting for a specific answer "because of dark money". If you want that hypothesis tested, it's best you ask separately.)

Comment: You're actually asking two questions in your 2nd para. The 2nd question in that para is broader. I assume you've added it mostly for rhetorical effect, otherwise your question is a duplicate of prior ones on that issue here, e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14957/why-are-third-parties-viable-in-many-democracies-but-not-the-usa

Comment: @F1Krazy taking his first poll *A majority of Americans agree with many of the Democratic presidential candidates in favoring some type of national health insurance plan, though most Americans still like the health insurance they currently have and do not want private insurance to be replaced by a public option.*  Then take the OP's comment elsewhere *Biden does not have a national public health care plan. Neither did Obama. Bernie Sanders did, but he is not a democrat.*.  Are these the same health plan?  No, goalposts are moving at speed here.  And the OP hadn't even cited any polls before.

Comment: Also, to take poll #3 environmental regulation.  What environmental regulation?  Painless?  For sure, everyone is on board with that one.  But if you, as a politician want to actually **do** something, support drops quickly.  For example, Washington, 
 a reliably Dem state with little fossil fuel industry to speak of : 
 https://time.com/5447748/washington-state-carbon-tax-climate-change/  So citing polls is not wrong but is also disproved by actual outcomes when it comes to voting.

Comment: @Italian:  Since the decision of the SCOTUS favoring Citizens United, the corporate class has now solidified its power over the political arena.  In other words, Republican and Democratic politicians are nothing more than the political arms of the corporate class of the USA.  The USA is a corporatocracy, not a democracy, and hence doesn't need to listen to the people.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a push question. OP's most recent comment makes it clear that they're fishing for a specific answer that fits their existing world view.

Comment: @Fizz - I added polling data to my answer that are broken down by party to support the claims I made in that answer.

Answer (score 7):

> When polled, the majority of Americans consistently believe in (1) a national health care plan; (2) increased taxes, not fewer taxes, on the wealthy; (3) and more, not less, environmental regulation, particularly on climate change.

A much better way to phrase this: When polled, the majority of Democratic-leaning Americans strongly agree with those three propositions. But when  Republican-leaning Americans are polled on these propositions, they strongly disagree with the first and last propositions, and are divided on the tax proposition. The majority of Republican Party donors disagree very strongly with the tax proposition.

These marked divisions in the opinions of party-leaning voters and donors explain the marked division between Democratic and Republican politicians on these issues.

**Update: Examples of polling on these propositions**

***Health care.***
The Kaiser Family Foundation recently reported on a poll conducted from [November 30 to December 8, 2020 regarding health care](https://www.kff.org/health-reform/poll-finding/5-charts-about-public-opinion-on-the-affordable-care-act-and-the-supreme-court/). One of the questions asked what people would like to see the next presidential administration and Congress do when it comes to the health care law (the Affordable Care Act). The vast majority (74%) of Democratic-leaning respondents wanted to see it expanded, while a majority (59%) of Republican-leaning respondents wanted to see it scaled back or repealed.

***Taxing the rich.*** In a [2019 survey conducted by the Rock Center for Corporate Governance at Stanford University](https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/publication-pdf/survey-us-tax-2019_0.pdf), 53% of Democrat-leaning voters thought that the marginal rate for the top income tax bracket should be higher while 37% of Republican-leaning voters thought it was about right, and 30% thought it should be lower.

***Environmental regulation, particularly on climate change.***
In a [2019 survey conducted by the Pew Research Center](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2020/04/21/how-americans-see-climate-change-and-the-environment-in-7-charts/), respondents were asked a pair of questions regarding policies aimed at reducing the effects of global climate change:

- Do such policies do more good than harm, do more harm than good, or make no difference when it comes to the environment? 71% of Democratic-leaning respondents responded do more good than harm while only 34% of Republican-leaning voters made this choice.
- Do such policies help, hurt, or make no difference when it comes to the economy? 47% of Democratic-leaning respondents responded that such policies would help the economy and only 13% said such policies would hurt the economy), while only 15% of Republican-leaning voters chose "help" and 52% chose "hurt".

Comment: Biden does not have a national public health care plan.  Neither did Obama.  Bernie Sanders did, but he is not a democrat.

Comment: This, I think, is the simplest and correct answer.  No one in Congress is beholden to the whole nation, only the particular subsets that vote in the elections for their seat. If the majority of voters in one party are against something then you can expect that party to be against it.  Doesn't matter that there's an overall national average, as that's not who they (ostensibly) represent and serve.

Comment: @BeginnerBiker I, along with many others, would construe the Affordable Care Act (ACA, aka Obamacare) of 2010 as a type of a national public health care plan. Maybe not a great one; it is what it is, and it is what was feasible at the time. President Biden has explicitly called out for expanding the ACA. On the other hand, many Republicans rejected the core concepts of the ACA a decade ago, and many still want to repeal the ACA to this day. The support for / rejection of the ACA is consistent with the opinions of those who consistently vote Democratic / consistently vote Republican.

Comment: @BeginnerBiker If you are of the opinion that a single payer healthcare plan is the one true "national healthcare plan", then not even a majority of Democratic-leaning voters would agree with you. Most voters (left or right) see the Affordable Care Act as a kind of a national healthcare plan. Some voters, most of whom are left-leaning voters, don't see the ACA as going nearly far enough. Other voters, most of whom are right-leaning voters, see it as going far too far. In the middle, many moderate voters see it as just about right.

Answer (score 4):

Because polling is often inaccurate due to a number of factors.  Merely changing the wording slightly can often have drastic effects on the outcome of the poll.  Like take gun control for example.  If you had a poll asking if people wanted to ban all semi-automatic guns, it would be more popular than a poll which asked the same thing but also explained that most rifles and nearly every pistol are semi-automatic.  They can also be inaccurate due to sampling errors; you'll get a much different result on the same question if you run the same poll in NYC and in the woods in Missouri.

Polls are also ignored because many politicians are elected by jurisdictions that don't neatly match the national average.  Imagine you're running for Congress in a district where almost every job is in the oil industry.  How many votes do you think you'll get if you vote for heavy carbon taxes?  It doesn't matter that those taxes may be popular with the rest of the country, *your* constituents will hate them.

Comment: Any proof that polling is inaccurate and other methods that are more accurate?  After all, countless polls indicate what I've stated.

Answer (score 4):

Because it seldom works this way [anywhere else](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219881?seq=1). Studies on the linkage between issue polling and political action find that it works like that maybe a third of the time.

As noted in that paper more qunatitatively, politicians find various reasons to ignore public opinion at large:

- issue salience: not getting voted out of office for it (David Siegel's answer)
- they want to act on their own ideology (i.e. base/core appeal -- David Hammen's answer)
- they think the public may be poorly informed (Ryan's answer, sort of)
- lobbying from narrow interests groups does counter the wider option to some extent (dandavis's answer)

In many instances, the above are not mutually exclusive explanations.

And to save my answer from trivially repeating the rest...
because the US is ["not a democracy"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/what-is-the-difference-between-a-republic-and-a-representative-democracy?), by which here I mean
that the US Senate [can substantially over-represent minority positions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49560/whats-roughly-the-smallest-percentage-of-the-us-population-that-through-its-s) (aka malapportionment).

Regarding the malapportionment aspect... interestingly enough there's (worldwide) correlation established with [lower] taxes in [a paper](https://publications.iadb.org/publications/english/document/Why-Dont-We-Tax-the-Rich-Inequality-Legislative-Malapportionment-and-Personal-Income-Taxation-around-the-World.pdf):

> Because  over-represented  districts  tend to  be  dominated  by  parties  aligned  with  the  elite,  these  groups can block legislative attempts to  introduce  progressive  taxes.  Using a  sample of  more  than 50 countries  (including  17  across  Latin  America)  between  1990  and  2007, this paper finds that i) countries with historically more unequal distributions of wealth and income systematically present higher levels of legislative malapportionment, and ii) higher  levels  of  malapportionment  are  associated  with  lower  shares  of personal income taxes in GDP.

More generally, mallapotionment [works](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2019/07/aoc-pelosi-feud-gerrymandering-why-cities-lose.html) against (other) liberal/progresive policies in other countries (too), as long as the
population mostly in favor of such measures is concentrated in cities. (And yeah, I realize I've not even [explicitly] talked about issue polls on this mallapotionment angle.)

But to actually touch on the latter, on top of that (and for somewhat more obscure reasons at least in part related to lobbying contacts) US Congresspersons [tend to overestimate](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2018/11/study-congress-overestimates-the-publics-conservatism.html) the conservatism *of their own district* on a range of issues like universal healthcare or minimum wage. (I guess a "standard" Republican answer to this is to say that the polls are wrong for various reasons, as seen in Ryan's answer.)

A more benign explanation is that party elites (including Congress' staffers) are [more polarized](https://news.stanford.edu/2017/12/20/political-parties-polarized-voters/) than the average constituent. But this explanation doesn't *uniformly* hold across all domains, in terms of its explanatory power/strength [e.g.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/american-political-science-review/article/abs/legislative-staff-and-representation-in-congress/D7735FCF39B843B9F3269FD39362FD66)

> we examined the role of staffers’ personal
> opinions. [...] We found the clearest case for egocentric bias in health policy. On average, staffers who
> supported the ACA repeal overestimated constituent
> support for repeal while staffers who opposed repeal
> underestimated constituent support for repeal. By
> contrast, all staffers underestimated their constituents’
> support for climate regulations, infrastructure spending, boosting the minimum wage, and gun background
> checks, although this dynamic was significantly moderated by staffers’ own beliefs. [...] Our evidence
> suggests that, despite any political incentives that may
> exist to reward unbiased estimation of constituent
> beliefs, staffers do not transcend common egocentric
> bias.

Somewhat more obviously, staffers who had more contacts with business lobbying groups were
reporting estimates of constituents' positions closer to the business groups' view (against climate regs, against raising minimum wage, etc.)

Basically the [weights of the] explanatory factors are not uniform across issues, which makes answering this questions rather difficult in an abstract setting (besides an enumeration of a host of possible reasons).

Answer (score 3):

The needs of the voter are beset by the needs of those who fund candidates.

Campaigns are largely financed by wealthy individuals who don't share the opinions of national audiences. When both side's financers are in agreement about an issue there's little chance of a politician taking the opposite stance, no matter how broadly popular it is.

In a way this harkens back to an original and legitimate debate around the country's founding. That is, who should control the government: those who own the country or those who live in it. Universal suffrage tends towards the latter, but modern campaign finance tends towards the owners.

If campaigns were publicly financed, politician's stances would more closely mirror public opinion.

Comment: I agree.  This is what we call a corporatocracy, not a democracy.

Answer (score 2):

Quite aside from the question of the accuracy of polls, and the degree to which national opinion may not be the same as opinion within any one state or district, few votes will choose to vote against an incumbent that they would have otherwise supported because of that incumbent's position on any single issue. Many will support the candidate of their party, whatever specific stands that legislator has taken. Many will support the incumbent if things are generally perceived as "going well" whatever that means to a particular voter. Some will condition support on some one particular issue, and ignore stands on other issues.

It is rare for a vote or even a series of votes on a particular issue by a Representative or Senator will change his or her constituents previous support to opposition in the next election that the legislator faces.

Answer (score 2):

### 1) national health care plan

First, it's not surprising that people want "some kind of health care".  The system is a mess *and gobbles up tons of money, including government spending*.

Taking the OP's cited poll:

> A majority of Americans agree with many of the Democratic presidential candidates in favoring some type of national health insurance plan, though most Americans still like the health insurance they currently have and do not want private insurance to be replaced by a public option.
>
> Meanwhile, more Americans today approve than disapprove of the 2010 Affordable Care Act, though many — including most Democrats — now think the law didn't go far enough.

As a Canadian, I agree, Obamacare did not go far enough.  But if you read the poll, "most Democrats" does not equal "most Americans".  And 48-49% of American voters, in 2012, voted for a platform specifically wanting to repeal Obamacare.

Second, there were significant forces against going much further, including on the Democrat side of things.  Workers that are unionized, civil servants or work for big companies often have pretty good health plans already.  It was not appealing to them to ditch their plans for a nationwide system.

On the Republican side, many label any single-payer plans as Socialism, by which they really mean Communism.  Never mind that US government spending is on par with other countries running a real national plan.  So it really does get a lot of grass roots pushback, including from people who would benefit.  Substance?  No.  Image.  Yes.

In psychology, it is common to privilege aversion to loss over hope of gain.  The US system is so messed up but also so impactful to individuals and so costly that many people will resist change in case it makes things worse.

Finally, the OP has a lot more ambition for their health care plan than the poll they cite:  *Biden does not have a national public health care plan. Neither did Obama. Bernie Sanders did, but he is not a democrat. – Beginner Biker*.

### (2) increased taxes, not fewer taxes, on the wealthy;

> A new poll is finding broad support for an annual wealth tax on people with assets of at least $50 million, underlining support for taxing the rich.

That's pretty much what one would call both a softball and two wolves and a sheep voting for dinner.

Is this typically the kind of tax increase that usually gets proposed?  No.  One Obama tax increase proposal started dinging up people from $250K on up.  Not $50M.  There the resistance towards tax increases becomes much more pronounced.

This particular poll might pass.  Would it solve budgetary problems?  Well, likely wouldn't hurt (but keep in mind France's *impot sur les grandes fortunes* / special-rich-tax never made much money).

Ideally, a broader tax increase would be sought, not just on the very, very wealth, but on the reasonably wealthy.  And maybe tax capital gains more aggressively while you are at it.

That's the kind of tax plan that gets pushed backed, not rose-colored ones like this poll.

### (3) and more, not less, environmental regulation, particularly on climate change.

> WASHINGTON, D.C. -- The majority of Americans say protection of the environment should be a priority, even at the risk of curbing economic growth, and believe the U.S. government is not doing enough to protect the environment. About three-quarters support spending more government money on solar and wind power, and support higher emissions and pollution standards for industry.
>
> Over Six in 10 Say Government Doing Too Little on the Environment
>
> Sixty-two percent of Americans currently say the government is doing too little to protect the environment, the highest in 12 years and well above the low point of 46% measured in 2010. The only time when the "too little" percentage was higher than 62% came in 1992, when Gallup first asked the question.

This is, again, a rather softball poll.  "We ought to do something" seems to be the idea.

I am going to counter with Washington state's [rejection of a carbon tax](https://time.com/5447748/washington-state-carbon-tax-climate-change/).  This is a largely Democratic state, with little fossil fuel interest.

When push came to shove and it came time to vote, people voted [against a $15/CO2 ton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Washington_Initiative_1631).

We are hitting the limits of this kind of poll here.  While people may want to "protect the environment" in the abstract, they most certainly also have an aversion to paying for it.  Or to modify their consumption habits.

### This is not a particularly novel problem

Any democracy can have a majority of people who feel "somewhat for" issue X.  This will show up in polls.

However, if a minority of people feel "strongly against" issue X, they can influence the vote by lobbying, funding.  And they are more likely to treat this vote as single-issue and vote for whoever is against it.

Even in the corporate world that holds true.  A number of corporations have indicated they'd prefer better, predictable, climate change regulations.  But the ones really at risk, like the coal mining companies, will fight it much more than the somewhat-support camp.

In the US, there is no better example of this strong aversion vs moderate support imbalance than gun control.  Any concrete proposal to limit guns is going to be fought tooth and nail by the pro-gun supporters but will only be one of many policies guncontrol-supporters will evaluate while casting their votes.

It would be ridiculous to argue that it's only corporate gun interest that are keeping the US gun laws as they are.

A small-ish minority of very committed voters beats a diffuse majority of "we ought to do somethings", *especially when they can can exploit US ideological fault lines to do so*.

And a politician ignoring this would not get elected.

**Last, governing by polls - the gist of the question - is not a particularly great recipe for good government.**

In fact, I would myself be for all 3, but I don't confuse my preferences with the capacity of a government to get elected and effect policy on such a platform, not without considerable negotiation and finesse.

Comment: Good point on concentrated vs diffuse interests in general. Some feel it applies to environmental regs (broadly speaking) too https://www.elgaronline.com/view/9781847200648.00016.xml